# CoordinatorLayout doesn't work like I want it to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this layout code in my activity. In `ViewPager` I have fragments that contains RecyclerView. When I scroll to the top of the list I have to scroll it again to have CoordinatorLayout expand. How can I do that in one seamless scroll:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="10dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:transitionName="obrazek"
            android:src="@drawable/placer" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:contentInsetStart="40dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
             />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity ="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_run_white_48dp" />
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` inside the `ViewPager` is not a part of your `CoordinatorLayout` so it can not coordinate the scrolling action.

Comment: you have to create a custom behavior from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html to do it.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with the `CoordinatorLayout`? Obviously it is the `CollapsableToolbarLayout`/`AppBarLayout` which refuses to expand. A custom behavior will probably fix that for you, but I suspect there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `app:layout_behavior` for your `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` . Setting `app:layout_behavior` to only `LinearLayout` will be suffice.

Comment: It stil behaves the same. I think Your answer is more of a optimization than solution.